# How to use dbutils.secrets in a spark jar

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

So I'm currently trying to set secrets for my Databricks development environment. I have successfully set these using the Databricks-cli. I am now trying to use these in my spark jar (written in scala). However it need to compile locally and the in ci/cd pipeline in order to be pushed live.

However I cannot find in which package `dbutils` is located.

`... = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "SCOPE", key = "VARIABLE")`

This is the usecase that I am trying to implement and would appreciate any help!

Comment: You can try to reference [databricks dbutils package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/dbutils-api_2.11)

Comment: @sgungormus well yes I have tried doing this. But nothing in that package in any of the sub packages hints to a dbutils.secrets import...Nor does intelliJ try to autocomplete it for me ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils`? 
My SBT build has a `"com.databricks" %% "dbutils-api" % "0.0.3"` dependency that seems to pull in the `dbutils`.

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks every job is starting from a notebook when your jar contains a business logic should be defined as a library attached to the cluster.

A start-up notebook usually deals with all external parameters using `dbutils` then invoke a business logic code passing passwords, connection strings, etc as a parameter to the function.

All secrets are stored in [KeyVault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) only. Here you can find [how to integrate Databricks secret scopes with KeyVault](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/secrets/secret-scopes.html)

To run code locally the password retrieved from KeyVault using Azure CLI and assigned to the environment variable as a preparation step before each run.